# How to convert Python string type annotation to proper type?

Tags: python, python-typing, python-3.10

Some Python type annotations can be specified as strings, to allow recursion for example. I however need to get at the proper type for runtime evaluation.  Strings are also used if I `from __future__ import annotations`, which is intended to be the default in Python 3.10 (If I read correctly). Given these strings I need to get at the proper type.

For example, in this code, the field type is `<class 'int'>` if I don't import from future, but `"ObjectId"` if I do. MOre importantly, the check for `... is int` is only true if I don't do the import.

```
# Toggle the comment on the next line
# from __future__ import annotations
import dataclasses

ObjectId = int

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Sample:
    id: ObjectId


def main() -> None:
    fields = dataclasses.fields(Sample)
    print(fields[0].type)
    print(fields[0].type is int)

main()
```

How do I convert the string based type annotation to a proper class type?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#resolving-type-hints-at-runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [typing.get_type_hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints)

```
from __future__ import annotations
import dataclasses
from typing import get_type_hints

ObjectId = int


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Sample:
    id: ObjectId


def main() -> None:
    hints = get_type_hints(Sample)

    print(hints['id'])
    print(hints['id'] is int)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
<class 'int'>
True
```

---

Note: I've found this method can be quite slow, so for the cost of memory I cache results:

```
from functools import cache
from typing import Any, Type, get_type_hints


@cache
def get_cached_type_hints(clazz: Type[Any]) -> dict[str, Type[Any]]:
    return get_type_hints(clazz)
```